# Python fitting with scipy curve_fit does not work properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I seem to have a Problem fitting a function to my data. Maybe someone can help me with this.

Data:

```
xValues = [65.2, 65.4, 65.1, 65.2, 65.4, 65.6, 65.5, 65.4, 65.5, 65.7, 65.6, 65.9, 65.7, 66.0, 66.1, 66.0, 66.3, 66.4, 66.4, 66.3, 66.3, 66.5, 66.6, 66.6, 66.6, 66.7, 66.8, 66.9, 66.8, 67.1, 67.0, 67.1, 67.1, 67.1, 67.2, 67.3, 67.5, 67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 67.8, 67.8, 67.9, 68.0, 68.1, 68.1, 67.9, 68.1, 68.2, 68.3, 68.4, 68.4, 68.6, 68.7, 68.7, 68.9, 68.8, 68.7, 68.9, 68.8, 69.0, 69.2, 69.3, 69.0, 69.2, 69.4, 69.6, 69.6, 69.7, 69.8, 69.7, 69.7, 69.6, 69.9, 69.7, 69.8, 70.0, 70.1, 70.2, 70.2, 70.2, 70.2, 70.5, 70.6, 70.6, 70.8, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 70.8, 71.0, 71.0, 71.2, 71.2, 71.1, 71.2, 71.4, 71.5, 71.7, 71.8, 71.8, 71.7, 71.7, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.1, 72.1, 72.0, 72.1, 72.3, 72.5, 72.4, 72.3, 72.4, 72.6, 72.6, 72.7, 72.9, 73.1, 73.0, 73.0, 73.3, 73.3, 73.2, 73.2, 73.4, 73.5, 73.5, 73.6, 73.6, 73.7, 73.8, 74.0, 73.9, 73.8, 73.9, 74.1, 74.2, 74.3, 74.4, 74.5, 74.6, 74.5, 74.4, 74.5, 74.7, 74.9, 74.9]

yValues = [57.4, 57.5, 53.2, 56.4, 47.3, 54.3, 60.4, 59.6, 59.2, 51.6, 53.1, 49.5, 54.9, 54.5, 56.0, 57.8, 54.7, 48.8, 55.7, 59.3, 54.6, 51.5, 43.6, 50.2, 55.3, 55.1, 59.9, 57.2, 60.0, 65.6, 64.0, 59.8, 59.9, 63.1, 67.4, 64.4, 58.7, 60.0, 55.6, 60.6, 58.7, 63.3, 67.3, 63.0, 60.5, 57.4, 60.1, 61.9, 62.8, 65.5, 62.0, 62.0, 69.7, 70.3, 72.0, 69.8, 67.1, 70.4, 63.3, 65.1, 65.1, 62.0, 64.9, 75.2, 69.6, 66.5, 63.9, 62.1, 66.2, 66.7, 66.5, 67.4, 69.6, 72.2, 73.1, 77.5, 73.5, 65.0, 74.0, 77.4, 74.8, 79.8, 84.2, 74.7, 69.5, 70.3, 70.1, 70.7, 74.4, 74.3, 73.3, 77.1, 73.8, 76.2, 71.3, 74.5, 74.5, 75.6, 75.5, 75.8, 73.5, 72.4, 75.3, 73.3, 74.9, 73.1, 78.9, 81.5, 80.6, 82.9, 79.1, 84.4, 79.8, 79.7, 79.8, 76.4, 80.5, 81.2, 88.0, 80.4, 81.2, 85.3, 79.3, 79.5, 82.4, 80.8, 80.1, 74.3, 76.3, 77.5, 78.9, 83.3, 82.9, 78.4, 80.8, 80.6, 84.8, 87.3, 86.4, 86.7, 85.5, 78.8, 81.1, 87.2, 87.1, 88.4, 85.6, 86.5, 88.8]
```

Function: #Also known as Worm-Like-Chain model for those who are interested in it...

```
def func(x,L,P): 
    return (((1.381*10**(-2)) * 295.15)/P) * (1/(4*((1-x/L)**2)) +x/L -1/4)

#Fitting function to data: 
#CurveFittingBlackMagic 
initialGuess = [50,1.0] 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,xRange,yRange, initialGuess ,maxfev=1000000000) 
print(popt) 
print(pcov) 
xFit = np.arange(0.0, 200, 0.01) 
plt.plot(xFit, func(xFit,*popt),'r', label = 'fit params: L=%5.3f, P=%5.3f'%tuple(popt))

plt.ylim(-20, 150) plt.xlim(-20, 200)

#Plotting Data plt.plot(xValues,yValues)

plt.show()
```

This yields the result shown in the picture which clearly is nonsense but i can not figure out why. Would be very awesome if someone could point out my mistake ;)

[image]

Comment: Consider formatting your question so it's actually legible

Comment: I'd say you initial guess is off. L defines the point of divergence. Looking at the shape of your data, I'd say it must be on the right hand side. You put it to the left. The chi^2 minimization will never push it on the other side. (200, 1) should work.

Comment: @Johan.Thanks but sadly changing the np.arange does not work

Comment: @mikuszefski: Yes the initial guess is not ver precise since i do not know the parameters. The data should be on the left side of the divergence and therefore (200,1) does not work either. But thanks anyways. I will try to taylor the damn function and see if i can get a reasonably well approximation that way.

Comment: @Johan, in think it is just missing a * in the middle. For some reason the * got lost in the question

Comment: Well, the formula just creates a curve that strongly resembles a straight line. You're probably better off using a real straight line given the very high fluctuations in the data.

Comment: @Johan: yeah i wish the damn model behind it would behave like a straight line... With the right parameters the formula looks more like a peak

Comment: Hi, I do not get the "therefore". I made the fit here and it looks ok. Eventually, I get something like (107, 0.14) as fit result. This is almost independent from the initial guess as long as L somewhat bigger  90

Comment: @mikuszefski yes you are 100% right. (100,1) actually did work. Just really expected the value to be between 5 and 10 which closed up my mind.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested. Fitting a taylor expansion of the function up to the 10th order did work and did give a good enough approximation of the function.

Comment: Did you try with `initialGuess = [107,0.14]` as suggested by  mikuszefski? Or with `initialGuess = [100, 1]` which should converge to something similar?

Comment: Yes i put in the result of the taylored fit into the starting values for the percise fit and it worked. Thanks for your help too Johan.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection your data looks like a linear function y(x)=ax+b . Blue line on the graph . Coefficients computed by linear least mean squares regression :

[image]

Considering the high scatter draw to think that a non-linear model is very uncertain. Computing the parameters in a non-linear model might lead to inconsistent result.

In fact your non-linear function is probably close to a linear function in the small range 64<x<76. If you expect a correct determination of the parameters L and P a much larger range of data should be necessary.

All this draw us to approximate the non-linear function by its tangent at  x_moy=70. The result is very close to the above linear regression. Next figure, green line.

[image]

Of course those numerical values of L and P are probably without signifiance because the optimum is so flat and uncertain.